# Javascript alert loop

Tags: javascript, macos, coda

I am very rookie when it comes to javascript, and I unwittingly created a alert which loops endlessly and means I cannot save the document and close the program.

Is there a way in surpassing the Javascript alert UI from the operating systems perspective, so I can still control the program.

I am running OSX 10.11.6 using Coda 2.

I cannot edit the code because the Javascript alert changes the focus to it then it appears, so then I close it another window appears.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Why can't you change the JS code to remove the infinite alerting loop?

Comment: well presumably `window.alert = null` or something will nuke that function. Assuming you have access to some sort of dev tools. If not...I don't think there is a universal way of stopping them. Which is probably why browsers will offer to stop it for you if you get more than one alert on a page.

Comment: regarding your edit: I don't think there is a way around that, I'm afraid. Or at least I don't know how you'd bypass it. You might need to force terminate the application from the OS.

Comment: The code cannot be edited because the window which appears cannot be closed because as soon as I close on down another one appears, and there is no way in cancelling the code without access to the program.

Comment: Force close the application and edit your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by hiding the program, then opening another document then going back to the document with the error I could save it. Then when I restarted I opened the program was able edit the code before It executed the code.